# Link two libraries to each other

Tags: c++, c, design-patterns, shared-libraries

I have a function in `libA.so` that is used in `libB.so`, 
And a function in `libB.so` that is used in `libA.so`! 
So defenetly i can not compile none of these libraries. 
How can I compile these two libraries?
Should i used third library and move the dependebcies to this library?
I used qt and c++

Updated:
in compile libA.so get error cannot find libB.so and in libB.so get error can not find libA.so

Comment: Putting common functionality in a separate library that can be reused is certainly a good idea.

Comment: "So defenetly i can not compile none of these libraries". This is simply not true. Try it, and if you get am error, ask a question about this specific error.

Comment: So how can do that?

Comment: @n.m. in compile libA.so get error cannot find libB.so and in libB.so get error can not find libA.so

Comment: The error is from the linker, not from the compiler. You do *not* need to tell the linker that `libA.so` needs `libB.so`. (Shared libraries don't work like DLLs). Just remove `-lB` from the command line. If you want, you can link `libA.so`, without `-lB`, then build `libB.so` and then re-link `libA.so` with `-lB`, but that's strictly optional.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add your comment "in compile libA.so get error cannot find libB.so and in libB.so get error can not find libA.so" to the question itself. Essential information should go to the question, not to the comments.

Comment: @n.m. if i remove -lB , compiler get error to not found function in libB class that i used in libA

Comment: It cannot possibly be the case. The compiler and the linker are two different things. The compiler knows nothing about the `-lB` flag. If you are getting a compiler error, you never reach the linker stage and `-lB` doesn't come into play. You should have removed only `-lB`, not any `-I` flags. Please [edit] the question and add a [mcve] with your actual compilation commands and actual error messages.

Answer (score 2):

**BIG FAT DISCLAIMER** Only do this if absolutely necessary. The preferred way is to refactor your project structure such that it doesn't contain dependency cycles.

When producing a shared library, the linker in general does not need to know about other shared libraries. One can use them on the command line but this is optional. Example:

```
// libA.cpp
extern void funcB();
void funcA() {
    funcB();
}
```

Compile and link:

```
g++ -fPIC -c libA.cpp
g++ -shared -o libA.so libA.o
```

`funcB` is supposed to live in `libB.so` but we are not telling the linker where to find it. The symbol is simply left undefined in `libA.so`, and will be (hopefully) resolved at *load time*.

```
// libB.cpp
extern void funcA();
void funcB() {
   funcA();
}
```

Compile and link, now using libA.so explicitly (ignore the infinite recursion, it's just an example):

```
g++ -fPIC -c libB.cpp 
g++ -shared -o libB.so libB.o -L/where/libA/is -lA
```

Now it is up to the executable to load `libB.so` before loading `libA.so`, otherwise `libA.so` cannot be loaded. It's easy to do so (just link the executable with only `libB.so` and not `libA.so`), but can be inconvenient at times. So one can re-link `libA.so` *after* building `libB.so`:

```
g++ -shared -o libA.so libA.o -L /where/libB/is -lB
```

Now one can link an executable to libA *or* libB and the other one will be picked up automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bit problematic for future re-use, you might want to either separate your functions differnetly between those libraries or create a third one thatt contains all of the "tool" funtions to have `LibA` and `libB` function without one another .

Answer (score 0):

> I have a function in libA.so that is used in libB.so, And a function in libB.so that is used in libA.so!

This is **wrong design**. A [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)) cannot, even indirectly, depend upon itself. Such a circularity is the symptom of something very wrong, and you are misunderstanding what a software library is (it is more than a random collection of functions, or of object files; it has to be somehow a "software module" and it is related to [modular programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) and often defines and implements *completely* a collection of *related* [abstract data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type)).

So **throw both `libA.so` and `libB.so` away**. And **make a *single* `libAB.so`** containing all the code that you have put in both `libA.so` and `libB.so` shared objects (and not genuine libraries).

The [answer from n.m.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52254180/841108) gives a technical way to solve your problem, but at heart your design is wrong and you are abusing libraries (and you cannot call your `libA` or your `libB` a library, even if you built them as some shared object in [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)).

You could also design your code by adding some indirection with [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)), or [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) or [function pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) held in some variable or data (and provide some way to set these callbacks, or initialize  the closures or the function pointers at *runtime*). Since you use [Qt](http://qt.io/), consider also defining appropriately  your new [Qt signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) (they are based on some callback machinery).

Read [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) and Drepper's [*How to Write Shared libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper for more.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I solve it.
As @n.m. said we dont need to link libA.so and libB.so in compile time, so I remove `-lA` and `-lB` when build them and i didnt get any error. And In app that want to use libA.so or libB.so I linked them with `-lA` or `-lB`. So this work correctly.